# 1d array into binary tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, tree

```
 nodeArray = [  3,  3,  7,   6,   6,   7,    15,    10,   10,    14,    13,    13,    14,    15,    23,    18,    18,    22,    21,    21,    22,    23,    0  ];

nodes = [];
links = [];

function  left(i) {
  return 2*i + 1;
}
function  right(i) {
  return 2*i + 2;
}
function  parent(i) {
  console.log("Parent =" + (i-1)/2);
  return (i-1)/2;
}

var index = 0;
do{
  if (index === 0) {
    var node = {
      'value': nodeArray[index],
      'child1_index': left(index),
      'child1_value': nodeArray[left(index)],
      'child2_index': right(index),
      'child2_value': nodeArray[right(index)],
      'parent_index' : 'null',
      'parent_value' : 'null'
    };
  } else {
    var node = {
      'value': nodeArray[index],
      'child1_index': left(index),
      'child1_value': nodeArray[left(index)],
      'child2_index': right(index),
      'child2_value': nodeArray[right(index)],
      'parent_index' :parent(index),
      'parent_value' : nodeArray[parent(index)],
      'index' : index
    };
  }
  nodes.push(node);
  index++;
} while (index != nodeArray.length)
console.log(nodes);
```

I have written the above code for future turning it into a binary tree with d3.js library, unfortunately all my parent node values (which are apparently given by any nodes `(index -1 )/ 2`.  give numbers like 5.5 etc being half the index or something. which obviously wont work. Some nodes give full integers then some do not.

example console output for one of my node objects. which looks right

```
Node1:
parent_index:0
parent_value:3
```

example of other node objects. which dont look right are

```
Node2:
parent_index:0.5
parent_value:undefined
```

Here is a jsfiddle if anyone's interested
http://jsfiddle.net/mryfw095/5/

Comment: I don't able to to understand what exactly you want as your result but for getting whole number use  Math.floor() or Math.ceil() function.

Comment: im trying to create a binary tree from a 1d array and the theory says the parent of a node is its index (value - 1) / 2. which for me ends with a  lot of non-integers. so ill try that approach and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want your `parent` function to round down.

```
function  parent(i) {
  console.log("Parent =" + Math.floor((i-1)/2));
  return Math.floor((i-1)/2);
}
```

Comment: yes thats all i was thinking, as the theory i read always says to use (i-1)/2 for the parent index but they never discuss non-integers. Ill give your idea a try and see what becomes of my tree. thanks

Comment: hmm i end up with a lot of undefined child nodes with this. hmm

Comment: as well they end up with indices that dont exist